# Order of Browserify Transforms

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, babeljs, brfs

Trying to write some code that uses babelify and then brfs

```
var wiz = browserify(root, watchify.args);
wiz.transform(babelify, {
    modules: 'common',
    global: true,
    ignore: /\/node_modules\/angular|.json/
});
wiz.transform('brfs');
```

but no matter what order I put the transforms in, browserify complains about there being `import/export` syntax which should be already taken care of by babel

```
{ [SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (1:0) while parsing file: C:\Users\splee_000\Documents\GitHub\experimental-theatre\audience_client_src\root.js]
```

How do I make sure the brfs transform happens after babelify?

Comment: Could you include the actual error/stacktrace?

Comment: You haven't told Babel to convert modules to anything, so it just leaves them in.

Comment: @loganfsmyth if I remove `wiz.transform('brfs');` it works though

Comment: Hmm, does the problem go away if you enable the `es2015` preset?

Comment: @loganfsmyth the question you marked is not a duplicate of mine, I'm transforming files in node_modules already and it is working

Comment: Yeah okay, was a little too fast there. I do think that is a likely solution to your problem though. The ordering looks fine to me.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I had to upgrade from babelify 6.x to 7.x for the preset option to work, it's still doing the same thing

Comment: https://github.com/substack/brfs/issues/39

Answer (score 1):

Global transforms are applied after non-global ones.

In your case you need to make `brfs` global too:

```
wiz.transform(require('brfs'), {global: true});
```